# Javascript/CSS - colResizable.js - Issues with controls lining up with TH

Tags: javascript

I'm just learning responsive web-design, and I'm having some issues with colResizable.js and the controls lining up with the table columns.  I'm hopeful someone will be willing to help out.

I can get the controls to work, but the table where it needs to work is way to the right on my page.  When I add the code for colResizable.js, the controls are way to the left.  The issue seems to reside with the *float:right* property that is listed for the table

Here is a fiddle for a better idea:
https://jsfiddle.net/qtxr1jt7/4/

I added the redlines to show where the controls are at.  I was able to move the red lines, but I wasn't able to actually move the controls that span the columns.

Can someone help me understand how I adjust the position of the controls?

Thanks

*It's too much code to post here, but StackOverflow is requiring a code-block in order to post a link to jsfiddle, so here it is:*

```
$("#table2").colResizable({
fixed:false,
liveDrag:true,
gripInnerHtml:"<div class='grip2'></div>", 
draggingClass:"dragging"});
```

Comment: Why use a javascript library when you can do this trick using plain CSS? Take a look here: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Comment: I've spent a long time just trying to figure out resizable columns with this javascript code.  It's almost working....

Comment: BUMP!  -- Maybe someone has an idea on this now....